# How filter text in shell interactively ("on fly")?

Tags: shell

windows 10, Emacs 26.1

```
M-x shell
```

[image]

I start Android application that very long time generate many lines in shell.

```
adb logcat -vtime
```

Here example:

[image]

In all of this text I need **only** lines that contain this text:

**com.example.myprojectname**

I need to filter this "on fly" interactively. It's very important.
So the result must be.

1. `M-x shell`
2. Start my Android app
3. On **shell** show ONLY lines that contains text **com.example.myprojectname**
4. This MUST be happen "on fly" interactively

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have a `grep` available, you can use `comint-preoutput-filter-functions` to do the filtering for you. You need to arrange for that variable to have the right value in `shell-mode`, which can be done using `add-hook`. Since `shell-mode` adds its own functions to that variable already, you need to perform the addition in the `shell-mode` hook function. Something like the following, which assumes your prompt starts with `$` or `~`

```
(defun my-comint-filter (str)
  (if (string-match "^\\$\\|^\\~\\|com\\.example\\.myprojectname" str)
      str
    ""))
(defun my-shell-mode-hook ()
    (add-hook 'comint-preoutput-filter-functions 'my-comint-filter t t))
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'my-shell-mode-hook)
```

Answer (score 2):

can you do the plain unix pipe trick of:

1. M-x shell
2. `myAndroidApp | grep --line-buffered -i com.example.myprojectname`

that is what I do.  Or are there special requirements?

as others have mentioned.  The text after the g*re*p command is a regular expression (the -i is a flag for case insensitive matching).  To get the pattern to match you may need to escape characters.  The escape mechanisms for bash (unix, linux, Mac etc) are different from MS Windows.  The escapes for Window's CMD are here: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html.  If you search for how to use grep, most of the examples will be for unix's bash.  Just a heads up.

Comment: I'm unsure what the current state of the the Linux Bash shell for Windows is, but @Alexei may need to [enable it](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/use-bash-shell-windows-10).

Comment: @slackline, oh good point.  I have not used Windows in years.  If the new embedded linux kernel is not enabled (I heard it works well), in the past, when on Windows, I used:  http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm. with great success.

Comment: @JamesAnderson I has Git, as result I has grep. But myAndroidApp | grep -i com.example.myprojectname not work correct. It start good, but then stop show anything.

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: @JamesAnderson But if I start this: myAndroidApp | grep -i com.example.myprojectname on Windows console (cmd.exe) than work FINE. It's success filtered "on fly".

Comment: @Alexei `grep` us using [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and as such `.` (periods) have a special meaning which means "any character" so you may want to escape it to match your string exactly.  I was going to modify the above but edits must be 6 characters but try `myAndroidApp | grep -i 'com\.example\.myprojectname'`

Comment: @slackline escape not help. Same result.

Comment: @Alexei [Try with `grep --line-buffered`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe/53445#53445)